# RxJavaCallAdapterFactory cannot be converted to Factory

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2

I'm trying to use Retrofit 2 and RxJava following the guide in this 
https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en

In section "RxJava Integration with CallAdapter
" explains how use RxJava with retrofit

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://api.nuuneoi.com/base/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

However during compilation there is the following error:

```
Error:(63, 71) error: incompatible types: RxJavaCallAdapterFactory cannot be converted to Factory
```

How can I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Did you include the dependencies mentioned ? compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'

Comment: yes, I include the dependencies compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'

Comment: @LuisaRepele Weird, but I had included all necessary dependencies and Android Studio still could not find `RxJavaCallAdapterFactory`. Then i manually add `import retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory;` and it worked.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Make sure you are using the same groupId and version for the main Retrofit dependency, the Gson converter dependency, and the RxJava adapter dependency.

I'm guessing yours look something like this:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2'
```

(Note that they use different groupIds and version numbers)

They should all look the same like this:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.2'
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention in version code as I was using  2.3.0 but then realised converter-gson was 2.1.0 that's why I got the error that can not resolve RxJavaCallAdapterFactory. However if I had a look in gradle file there was all set of libraries.

Comment: I am using com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2 and right now it is not possible to update this library. What can I do in this case ?

Answer (score 2):

Currently adding "com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0" gives following error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/rxjava.properties
```

But, instead, adding "compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0",makes packaging successful

Comment: This is still true as of March 9th, 2017. I'm using retrofit 2.2.0, jakewharton's rxjava2-adapter 1.0.0, rxandroid 2.0.1, and rxjava 2.0.7.

Comment: Actually you should import `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.2.0'`, and then use `.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())`

Answer (score 1):

change your retrofit rxjava adapter into

```
  implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofit_version"
```

And change your CallAdapterFactory into

```
.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
```

it will look something like this

```
.baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use updated and latest libs.

```
// retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava3:2.9.0'

    // rxjava3
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.0'
```

NOTE :: **RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create() instead of RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()**

```
Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://datanapps.com")
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()
```